# Storing data on SD Card in Android

Tags: android, sd-card

Using the [data-storage page in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), I've tried to store some data to the SD-Card.
This is my code:

```
    // Path to write files to
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                  "/Android/data/"+ctxt.getString(R.string.package_name)+"/files/";
    String fname = "mytest.txt";

    // Current state of the external media
    String extState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    // External media can be written onto
    if (extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        try {
            // Make sure the path exists
            boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();  
            if (!exists){ new File(path).mkdirs(); }  

            // Open output stream
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(path + fname);

            fOut.write("Test".getBytes());

            // Close output stream
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I create the new FileOutputStream I get a FileNotFound exception. I have also noticed that "mkdirs()" does not seem to create the directory.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm testing on an AVD with a 2GB sd card and "hw.sdCard: yes", the File Explorer of DDMS in Eclipse tells me that the only directory on the sdcard is "LOST.DIR".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you given your [application permission to write to the SD Card](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/security/security.html#manifest)?

You do this by [adding the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Its the simple things that make the big difference... Thanks! =)

Answer (score 2):

Before reading or writing to SD card, don't forget to check the SD card is mounted or not?

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
```