# How to check if newly created folder is present into SD Card in Android

Tags: android, sd-card

From my application, I want to store some images into my SD card. For that I need to create a one folder.

At the first time folder will create but after it checks whether that folder is present or not. How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895853/storing-data-on-sd-card-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295041/saving-canvas-drawing-to-sd-card

Answer (score 29, accepted):

below code will create a directory if it does not exist

```
   File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/New Folder");

   if(!direct.exists())
    {
        if(direct.mkdir()) 
          {
           //directory is created;
          }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. For addding image to that folder what i will do?

Comment: save the image to sd card from canvas

Comment: Couple of notes: you should be checking getExternalStorageDirectory() for a null return and/or calling getExternalStorageState() first.  To save a file in your new directory, do "File ofile = new File(direct, ofilename);" and "FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(ofile);".  Then write your image data to fw.  Don't forget to close it when you're done.  Wrapping it in a BufferedWriter might improve performance, depending on your application.

Comment: What if I want to create multiple level folder. For example /New Folder1/New Folder2 ? Is there a simple call like ios sdk does? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You should request the following permission first in your Android manifest :

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

and execute above code  by Rasel for it to work.