# Folder not created by app in android

Tags: android, android-file

I am creating a folder through my app

```
File direct_playlist = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + PLAYLIST_PATH);

            if(!direct_playlist.exists())
             {
                 if(direct_playlist.mkdir()); //directory is created;

             }
```

Even though the command executes perfectly I can not see the folder in Explorer. I have also given permission to my app in the manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

When I try to access this folder my app crashes as the folder is not present.

Comment: Please give the Path included in PLAYLIST_PATH.

Comment: check this link it's may be you http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-create-sub-folder-in-sd-card.html

Comment: try to change mkdir() to mkdirs() also

Comment: @AppMobiGurmeet: static final String PLAYLIST_PATH = "ContentRenderer/Playlists";

Comment: thanks @user1049280 that helped . but I am still wondering what difference did it cause

Comment: refer docs : mkdirs Creates the directory named by the trailing filename of this file, including the complete directory path required to create this director, that means it will create all the required missing folders unlike mkdir

Comment: @Ankuj: It is a directory created under the directory.So mkdirs() will work for you.is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

This topic is already discussed So Use Following threads..

[How to check if newly created folder is present into SD Card in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911041/android-how-to-create-folder-into-sd-card)

[Creating a directory in /sdcard fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853472/creating-a-directory-in-sdcard-fails)

It will surely help you.

Comment: Use "/" instead of File.seprator...may  be they help. And If your playlist path contain more than one directory..Use "direct_playlist.mkdirs()"...