# Can not write to sdcard

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm trying to create folder on the SDCard on Android 2.3 device:

```
final File downloadFolder = new File(FILES_PATH);
        if (!downloadFolder.exists()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating tmp directory: " + downloadFolder.mkdirs());
        }
```

And mkdirs() returns false. FILES_PATH is the same that getExternalStorage() returns - /mnt/sdcard/.tmp/
SD card is writable from the cli with root.
Permission:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.venturezlab.tvupdater"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911041/android-how-to-create-folder-into-sd-card/6911090#6911090

Comment: What did you want say? I do exactly the same.

Comment: check your FILES_PATH.Is it formed correctly.

Comment: FILES_PATH is /mnt/sdcard/.tmp, it equals to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + ".tmp"

Answer (score 1):

Try `mkdir()` instead of `mkdirs()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final File downloadFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/.tmp");
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question. FILES_PATH is /mnt/sdcard/.tmp

Comment: change FILES_PATH to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: I've checked, /mnt/sdcard is the return value of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). And it has link /sdcard/

Comment: But, have you tried it with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory?

Comment: Yes, first of all I tried this method, it returned the string that is exactly FILES_PATH. I use constant because this software is only for one specific device and I'm sure that the path will never change.