# How can I move files on my computer to my Android SD card using ADT?

Tags: android, file, adt, sd-card, transfer

I am new to Android, so hopefully someone can help me out. I want to move three files to my Android SD Card programmatically using Android Development Tools. I already included the WRITE-PERMISSIONS in the Android Manifest file. I found this code to create a directory from [How to check if newly created folder is present into SD Card in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911041/how-to-create-folder-into-sd-card-in-android)":

```
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/New Folder");

    if(!direct.exists())
    {
        if(direct.mkdir()) 
        {
            //directory is created;
        }

    }
```

Now I just need code to that can put files in the folder in the spot where it says "//directory is created;". Anyone know of a method to do this? Please help and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy files from internal storage to SD card. A detailed answer is here [How to move/rename file from internal app storage to external storage on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770004/how-to-move-rename-file-from-internal-app-storage-to-external-storage-on-android).

Comment: Can I ask you a follow up question?
I'm pretty sure this is a noob question, but internal app storage would mean anyplace in my project's folders right? For example, a file in res/drawable-hdpi

Comment: Internal storage means the device memory. This may help http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.

Comment: Gaaah. Then this doesn't solve my problem. My app will be installed on multiple devices (Some of which I will not come in contact with), so I won't have access to the internal memory or sd card. I need a way so that when the app installs, it moves these files into the SD Card. I want to store three pictures somewhere in my project folders, and on install, I want to move them to the SD Card. Any other suggestions?